# Excel VBA Code is running, despite the workbook having been closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with some VBA code running in it. It takes the place of a piece of simple CRM software, managing our stock, prats list, drawing index and service records.

It acts as a client and talks to various databases on our internal server, which means multiple people can use it at the same time.

The code is spread across 4 modules in the client workbook.

I have a routine that runs every time the workbook opens, which generates a landing page for the user (also checks for updates and permissions).

I also have a routine that looks for the enter key being pressed, this is so that you can hit enter to activate a search.

That all works fine, other than the normal bugs and changes I'm chasing / adding.

However, if you:

- Open the client
- Open another workbook
- Close the client
- Hit enter in the other workbook

The landing page for the client appears in the other workbook (which has a clear page function, so the contents are lost and the undo function wont get it back) and the client reopens.

It seems that after closing the client excel runs it's code in a "phantom" style.

This doesn't happen when the client workbook with all the code in it is still running and if you check the VBA editor after closing the client, it shows there being no code available to run.

If all workbooks are closed and then a workbook is opened, this behaviour doesn't occur.

That's the problem, has anyone had any experience with this behaviour?

Does anyone know how to stop excel executing code from a closed workbook?

The question got closed and I have been asked to provide code, this is a bit difficult as there is a lot of code here and I'm not sure which bit might be triggering, but I'll put what I think might be the culprits here:

This is in the ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub workbook_Open()

Call homePageGen
```

End Sub

This is the sheet1 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "checkEnter"
Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "checkEnter"
```

End Sub

This is the checkEnter routine:

```
Public Sub checkEnter()

Set A = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = A.ActiveSheet

If x.Cells(7, 5).Value <> "" And x.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Find A Drawing" Then

    Call filterPlant
    
End If

If x.Cells(7, 11).Value <> "" And x.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Find A Drawing" Then

    Call findDrawing
    
End If

If ActiveCell.row = 7 And x.Cells(3, 2).Value = "searchPartsPage" Then

    Call searchParts
    
End If

activeRow = ActiveCell.row
activeColumn = ActiveCell.column

x.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn).Select
```

End Sub

This is the homePageGen routine:

```
Public Sub homePageGen()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim A As Workbook
Dim x As Worksheet

Set A = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = ActiveSheet

Call clrPg(x)

If checkVersion = False Then
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("This is not the most recent version of this application please use the updated version found in the Internal Software folder, in the Public drive")
    
    Exit Sub
    
End If

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("B3", "C5"), "findPageGen", "Find A Drawing")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("E3", "F5"), "addDrawing", "Add A Drawing")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("B8", "C10"), "homePageGenPart", "Part Index")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("E8", "F10"), "viewAllChangeNotes", "Change Note Index")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("H3", "I5"), "viewSentFilePacks", "Sent File Packs")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("H8", "I10"), "homePageJob", "Job Records")

Call crtBtn(x, x.Range("B13", "C15"), "serviceRecordPageGen", "Service Records")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Please note that the checkVersion routine will run an update routine if the version is out of date.

Comment: Might need to share some relevant code. Are you working with application-level events, by chance?

Comment: What about checking that a certain filename is open and exit if it is not?

Comment: I Guess you use Application.Onkey
Why not release this when closing the workbook?

Comment: Yes I am using application level events, I've will add some code for them to the original question.

Comment: Yes I am using application.onkey, would you mind expanding on what you mean by release it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133180)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue
If you call your OnKey Setting leaving the argument for the procedure the Key will be reset to its original meaning

Comment: Ah ok, I see thank you, I suppose I could set that to run on workbook close. My only issue with this is that the checkEnter routine should not call the homePageGen routine (which is the one that clears the page and appears top be running in the other workbooks) so I worry that this would just be treating a symptom and not the actual disease.

Comment: @RedHare Thank you, your suggestion has worked, there is no more triggering. 

I am slightly worried that there might be something else that might trigger a bit of phantom code but I don't have any other listeners so I think I might be safe!

Merry Christmas if you celebrate it and thank you again - Rob